# Pull data from HDFS to Kafka using third party service

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs

How can I monitor HDFS files and directories and send them to Kafka and delete them afterwards? HDFS and Kafka are secured by Kerberos.

As far as I know, Flume does not support watching HDFS and Kafka-connect allows only to import data from Kafka to HDFS.

Comment: NiFi is an option in your case. You can have a look at the service provided by Nifi and see if it suits your requirements.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you pulling from HDFS into Kafka? Would it make more sense to stream the data to Kafka _before_ it goes to HDFS?

Comment: @Abhinav, does Nifi has a standalone script that can be executed from the command line?

Comment: @makar Nifi has its own UI through which you can stream your data.

Comment: Spark Streaming can monitor HDFS folders and send to Kafka. Done it before, but don't have the code anymore

Comment: @Abhinav I don't need UI, what I need is a standalone script-programme that can be run through command line.

Comment: Nifi workflows can be triggered from a REST API. Or you just leave Nifi running all the time. It'll periodically check for files on an HDFS path... If you just want a one time action, then write the Spark or MapReduce code to do it. Asking for libraries or tools is off topic for Stackoverflow